# Is there a way to get offset for each message consumed in kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In order to avoid reading of messages which are processed but missed to get committed when a KAFKA STREAMS is killed , I want to get the offset for each message along with the key and value so that I can store it somewhere and use it to avoid the reprocessing of  already processed messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  See the FAQ entry at http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#accessing-record-metadata-such-as-topic-partition-and-offset-information.

I'll copy-paste the key information below:

> **Accessing record metadata such as topic, partition, and offset information?**
>
> Record metadata is accessible through the [Processor API](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-processor-api).
>   It is also accessible indirectly through the [DSL](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl) thanks to its
>   [Processor API integration](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-process).
>
> With the Processor API, you can access record metadata through a
>   `ProcessorContext`. You can store a reference to the context in an
>   instance field of your processor during `Processor#init()`, and then
>   query the processor context within `Processor#process()`, for example
>   (same for `Transformer`). The context is updated automatically to match
>   the record that is currently being processed, which means that methods
>   such as `ProcessorContext#partition()` always return the current
>   record’s metadata. Some caveats apply when calling the processor
>   context within `punctuate()`, see the Javadocs for details.
>
> If you use the DSL combined with a custom `Transformer`, for example,
>   you could transform an input record’s value to also include partition
>   and offset metadata, and subsequent DSL operations such as `map` or
>   `filter` could then leverage this information.